# Webinar woes, won't play in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: firefox, video, chromium, media

I'm trying to view this [webinar](https://aa314.gondor.co/webinar/primary-analysis/), but it won't play in Firefox or Chromium under 14.04LTS.

How can I begin to diagnose what is going wrong?

Comment: Please explain your situation in more detail. What do you see in the browser window? What do you expect to see? Do you have Flash player working on other web sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site attempts to load insecure scripts. The loading of the Scripts will be blocked by the browser.

In this specific case it is probably because that some scripts be loaded via a connection without SSL.

Open the URL and click the marked icon:

- Chrome/Chromium

  [image]
- Firefox

  [image]

Comment: That worked. Should I be worried about those insecure scripts?

Comment: That I can not answer you. Everyone needs to decide for themselves. In this specific case it is probably because that some scripts be loaded via a connection without SSL.